# Is it possible to print html from an external page by replacing strings?

Tags: php

I was wandering if it were possible to store a html schema page with special strings to replace with variable and how to do it.

In an external file, I would like to put the html structure of a product, let's call it `schema.php`:

```
<span id="{% id %}">{%= name %}</span>
<span>{%= imageURL() %}</span>
```

The example above is just a simpler example. In the external file, the html would be more complex. I know that if there were just few lines I could just echo them with a simple function but this is not the case.

In another file I have a class that handle products, let's call it `class.php`:

```
class Product {
    //logic that is useless to post here.

    public function imageURL() {
        return "/some/url".$this->id."jpg";
    }
}
```

In this class I would like to add a function that take the content from `schema.php` and then echo it in the public file for users.

I tried with `file_get_contents()` and `file_put_contents()` but it just doesn't work:

```
$path_to_file = 'data/prodotti/scheda.inc';
$file_contents = file_get_contents($path_to_file);

$file_contents = str_replace(
  "{%= ",
  "<?php echo $this->",
  $file_contents
);

$file_contents = str_replace(
  " }",
  "; ?>",
  $file_contents
);

file_put_contents($path_to_file, $file_contents);
```

is it possible to call `schema.php` page and print it with custom variables?

Comment: `DOMDocument` might be your best bet.

Comment: Google for php template libraries

Comment: What you have should work. Except instead of `$file_contents = str_replace(
  " }",` you need `$file_contents = str_replace(
  " %}",` given your example data.

Answer (score 0):

By "schema page" I think you mean "template" and yes, but the best way to do it is to use an existing templating engine such as [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) or a Mustache implementation like https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php instead of implementing it yourself because of the risks of XSS, HTML-injection, and how you'll eventually want features like looping and conditionals.

Comment: I guess that mustache is the best option because it is shipped with composer. I cannot install anything on my server. However I didn't want to learn another template.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it normaly with php require func. without any strings to replace, if you just want to use that file as "template" then:

**in schema.php:**

```
<?php
echo'<span id="'.$id.'">'.$name.'</span>
<span>'.$imageURL.'</span>';
?>
```

**in class.php:**

```
<?php
class Product {
//logic that is useless to post here.

public function imageURL() {
    return "/some/url".$this->id."jpg";
}
}
$imageURL = imageURL(); ?>
```

**Index.php or whatever the main page that handles class.php and temp.php(schema)**

```
<?php
//avoid undefined variables on errors
//in case that you don't check for values submitted
$id = 0;
$name = 0;
$imageURL = '';

//set vars values 
$id = /*something*/;
$name = /*something 2*/;
$imageURL = /*something3*/;
//all date will be replaced is ready, oky nothing to wait for
require('path/to/schema.php');
```

**Note:** If you gets these data from user, then you should validate with `if(isset())`.

hope that helps,

Comment: @dcdeiv  if that's not what you want, i would misunderstood then, just make it clearer and i'll do my best to help :)